# Как использовать функцию МАХ для группировки значений в запросе SQL?

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица:

```
id  order  timeStamp
0   1      0
1   1      23
2   1      98
3   2      2
4   2      40
5   2      65
```

Мне нужно написать SQL запрос к ней чтобы в результате была таблица с уникальными order и соответствующими максимальными timeStamp. Что то вроде:

```
id  order  timeStamp
2   1      98
5   2      65
```

Подозреваю что тут надо использовать функцию MAX, но не понимаю как. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: если id этих записей вам не нужен, то уберите его из выборки. Если нужен, то сначала выберите максимальные значения, а потом приджойньте их. Или сделайте самоджойн таблицы со сравнением timestamp

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию. Вообще же - лучше использовать нумерацию в CTE либо FIRST_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

Если id не нужен, то можно вот так

```
SELECT 
    order, 
    MAX(timeStamp) timeStamp 
FROM 
    -- your table
GROUP BY 
    order;
```

а если с id то вот так

```
select b2.id, b1.order, b1.timeStamp 
      from (
          SELECT 
              order, 
              MAX(timeStamp) timeStamp 
          FROM 
              -- your table
          GROUP BY 
              order
          )b1
      join -- your table     b2 
          on b2.order = b1.order 
          and b2.timeStamp = b1.timeStamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, order, MAX(timeStamp) AS timeStamp FROM table GROUP BY order
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Сиквел тут будет ругаться, что `id` непонятно какой брать, если их много в группе окажется.